# Service variable updates but in component don't

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have this variable that gets record of image upload progress, it aparentlly work, but in my component it stays undefined.

**Upload Service method**

```
 uploadProfilePic(url:string, user_id:string, image:any) {
    this.imgComp.compress(image)
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(compressedImage => {
        try {
          var formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("profile_photo", compressedImage, compressedImage.name);
          formdata.append("user_id", user_id);
          this.http.put(url, formdata, { reportProgress: true, observe:'events' }).subscribe( event => {
            if(event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
              this.upload_progress = Math.round(event.loaded / event.total * 100)
              console.log(this.upload_progress)
            } else if(event.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
              this.toast.showToast(`Your profile pic has been updated!`)
              //this.upload_progress = undefined
              console.log(this.upload_progress)
              //setTimeout(function(){ location.reload() }, 4000)
            }      
          })
        } catch (error) {
          this.toast.showToast(error.message)
        }
      })
  }
```

I'm ussing this image compressor service, but i guess it's really not something that could cause the problem

**Upload Service constructor**

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient, public env: EnvService, private toast: Ion_Toast, private imgComp: ImageCompressorService) { }
```

Then i call it in my component:

```
constructor(
    private modalController: ModalController,
    public imgUploader: ImageUploadService
  ) { }
```

To be shown in the document:

```
<ion-progress-bar value="{{imgUploader.upload_progress/100}}"></ion-progress-bar>
<h1>{{imgUploader.upload_progress}}</h1>
```

I also checked if the service was on the app-module and everithing seems to be fine.

**App-Module**

```
providers: [
    ImageUploadService
  ],
```

I don't know if i should declare also the compressor on the providers, if maybe that could fix it.

**EDIT**

My input doesn't use the upload method directly, it uses a select image method first

**ImageUploadService**

```
upload_progress: number

selectProfilePic(event, user_id) {
    this.uploadProfilePic(`${this.env.API_URL}/users/update_profile_image`, user_id, <File>event.target.files[0])
  }
```

Comment: try changing this `value="{{imgUploader.upload_progress/100}}"` to `[value]="imgUploader.upload_progress/100"`

Comment: AFAIK both syntax works, even if the one you suggested is the recommended syntax I doubt it'll fix the problem. But it's worth trying.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to directly access service values in components. Maybe that's why it does not work.

I can suggest another approach: use an observable in your service which you subscribe to in your component.

Example:

```
class Component {
  uploadProgress: number;
  
  constructor(
    imgUploader: ImageUploadService
  ) {}

  onUpload() {
    this.imgUploader
      .uploadProfilePic() // Must return an observable of the progress value
      .subscribe(progress => (this.progress = progress));
  }
}

class ImgUploaderService {
 uploadProfilePic(url:string, user_id:string, image:any) {
    const uploadProgress = new BehaviorSubject(0);
    
    this.imgComp.compress(image)
      .pipe(take(1))
      // ... subscribe and update the progress in your behavior subject

    return uploadProgress.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Some help on BehaviorSubjects: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/BehaviorSubject. You may need asObservable(), next(), error() and complete() methods.

If it's not clear or you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, i guess it's due to where the ` return uploadProgress.asObservable()` goes. I've set it at the end of the try. Also i blendend both methods so it will return the observable.

Comment: @CarlosRodriguez can you send me a link with your code ? Like pastebin or something